# how to open call pickup screen in flutter app like whatsapp or instagram?

Tags: flutter, notifications, background-process, voip-android

I am working on a VoIP app, I have no idea how to open the call pickup screen in the background and when the phone is locked

"I tried to open a Flutter screen when I received a Flutter notification."

```
 android:showWhenLocked="true"
 android:turnScreenOn="true"
```

I added this code to AndroidManifest.xml

When the app is open and the phone locks, the entire app is accessible without unlocking.

Comment: try to check flutter_local_notifications/awesome_notifications pacakge and create a full screen notification.
this way you can achieve the behavior you want.

you can see these threads,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67302972/fcm-notification-on-locked-screen-flutter

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275569/whatsapp-like-call-notification-when-app-in-background-in-flutter